# Scrapy xpath with following sibling between two h2 tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I have a poorly designed HTML page from which I am trying to extract data using scrapy. The following snippet is the one that I am interested in:

```
<html>
    <h2 class="schoolName">Graduate School of Business</h2>
        <ul title="Graduate School of Business departments - part 1"></ul>
        <ul title="Graduate School of Business departments - part 2"></ul>
        <ul title="Graduate School of Business departments - part 3"></ul>
   <h2 class="schoolName">School of Law</h2>
       <ul title="School of Law departments - part 1"></ul>
       <ul title="School of Law departments - part 2"></ul>
  <h2 class="schoolName">School of Medicine</h2>
      <ul title="School of Medicine departments - part 1"></ul>
</html>
```

I specifically want to know the number of schools and the number of departments under each school.
So I find the list of all schools as follows:

```
>>> schools = response.xpath('//h2[@class="schoolName"]/text()').getall()
>>> schools
['Graduate School of Business', 'School of Law', 'School of Medicine']
```

Then for each school I find the departments under them as follows:

```
>>> for school in schools:
...     print(school)
...     print(response.xpath(f'//h2[@class="schoolName"][text()[contains(.,"{school}")]]/following-sibling::ul/@title').extract())
...     print ("-----------------------------")
...
Graduate School of Business
['Graduate School of Business departments - part 1', 'Graduate School of Business departments - part 
 2', 'Graduate School of Business departments - part 3', 'School of Law departments - part 1', 
 'School of Law departments - part 2', 'School of Medicine departments - part 1']
-----------------------------
School of Law
['School of Law departments - part 1', 'School of Law departments - part 2', 'School of Medicine 
departments - part 1']
-----------------------------
School of Medicine
['School of Medicine departments - part 1']
-----------------------------
```

This is obviously not working as expected since the following-sibling is selecting all **ul** tags and not just those between two **h2** tags. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One technique is to pick a common divider element that marks the beginning of a new block of info, use `count()` and `preceding-sibling` to measure its position, then select all the data elements that have the same number (plus one) of divider preceding siblings.

In an iPython shell:

```
In [1]: from lxml import etree

In [2]: string = '''<html>
   ...:     <h2 class="schoolName">Graduate School of Business</h2>
   ...:         <ul title="Graduate School of Business departments - part 1"></ul>
   ...:         <ul title="Graduate School of Business departments - part 2"></ul>
   ...:         <ul title="Graduate School of Business departments - part 3"></ul>
   ...:    <h2 class="schoolName">School of Law</h2>
   ...:        <ul title="School of Law departments - part 1"></ul>
   ...:        <ul title="School of Law departments - part 2"></ul>
   ...:   <h2 class="schoolName">School of Medicine</h2>
   ...:       <ul title="School of Medicine departments - part 1"></ul>
   ...: </html>'''

In [3]: root = etree.fromstring(string)

In [4]: schools = root.xpath('//h2[@class="schoolName"]/text()')

In [5]: schools
Out[5]: ['Graduate School of Business', 'School of Law', 'School of Medicine']

In [6]: for school in schools:
   ...:     print (school)
   ...:     position = int(root.xpath(f'count(//h2[text()="{school}"]/preceding-sibling::h2) + 1'))
   ...:     print (f"Position: {position}")
   ...:     print (root.xpath(f'//ul[count(preceding-sibling::h2) = {position}]/@title'))
   ...: 
Graduate School of Business
Position: 1
['Graduate School of Business departments - part 1', 'Graduate School of Business departments - part 2', 'Graduate School of Business departments - part 3']
School of Law
Position: 2
['School of Law departments - part 1', 'School of Law departments - part 2']
School of Medicine
Position: 3
['School of Medicine departments - part 1']
```