# Hi: How to select following sibling up to an specific node?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I have an enormous doubt, I don't know why next XPATH expression:

```
//div[@class='block-body js-replyNewMessageContainer']/article[1]//div[contains(@class, 'message-content')]//div[@class='bbWrapper']/div/b[not(span)][1]/following-sibling::b[1]/preceding-sibling::a
```

Is not working on the next site:

https://flipax2.net/threads/pack-prensa-de-espa%C3%B1a-29-abril-2021-varios-servidores.28/

The important part of the HTML tree is the following:

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<b><span style="color: Red"><span style="font-size: 26px">Pack : Prensa Española 29 Abril 2021</span></span><br>
<br>
<br>
ABC<br>
AS<br>
El Mundo<br>
El País<br>
Expansión<br>
Marca<br>
Sport<br>
...-...<br>
La Razón<br>
La Vanguardia<br>
La Voz de Galicia<br>
Mundo Deportivo<br>
...-...<br>
20 Minutos Madrid<br>
El Correo Bizkaia<br>
Gara<br>
La Gaceta de Salamanca<br>
La Mañana<br>
La Nueva España<br>
Viva Málaga<br>
Viva Sevilla<br>
...-...<br>
ABC de la Náutica<br>
Alfa y Omega (ABC)<br>
Cuídate (El Mundo)<br>
La Luna de Metropoli (El Mundo)<br>
LifeStyle (La Razón)<br>
Motor (El Mundo)<br>
Shopping &amp; Style (El Pais)<br>
<br>
<br>
<span style="font-size: 18px">PDF - Comprimido - 395 MB</span></b><br>
<br>
<br>


    
    
        
        
    


    <div class="lbContainer lbContainer--inline" title="" data-xf-init="lightbox" data-lb-single-image="1" data-lb-container-zoom="1" data-lb-trigger=".js-lbImage-_xfUid-1-1619754152" data-lb-id="_xfUid-1-1619754152">
        
            <div class="lbContainer-zoomer js-lbImage-_xfUid-1-1619754152" data-src="https://i.imgur.com/Weh6xtV.png" aria-label="Zoom"></div>
        
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Weh6xtV.png" data-url="https://i.imgur.com/Weh6xtV.png" class="bbImage" data-zoom-target="1" style="">
    </div>

 

    
    
        
        
    


    <div class="lbContainer lbContainer--inline" title="" data-xf-init="lightbox" data-lb-single-image="1" data-lb-container-zoom="1" data-lb-trigger=".js-lbImage-_xfUid-2-1619754152" data-lb-id="_xfUid-2-1619754152">
        
            <div class="lbContainer-zoomer js-lbImage-_xfUid-2-1619754152" data-src="https://i.imgur.com/AG9h566.png" aria-label="Zoom"></div>
        
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AG9h566.png" data-url="https://i.imgur.com/AG9h566.png" class="bbImage" data-zoom-target="1" style="">
    </div>

 

    
    
        
        
    


    <div class="lbContainer lbContainer--inline" title="" data-xf-init="lightbox" data-lb-single-image="1" data-lb-container-zoom="1" data-lb-trigger=".js-lbImage-_xfUid-3-1619754152" data-lb-id="_xfUid-3-1619754152">
        
            <div class="lbContainer-zoomer js-lbImage-_xfUid-3-1619754152" data-src="https://i.imgur.com/avMMBqE.jpg" aria-label="Zoom"></div>
        
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/avMMBqE.jpg" data-url="https://i.imgur.com/avMMBqE.jpg" class="bbImage" data-zoom-target="1" style="">
    </div>

 

    
    
        
        
    


    <div class="lbContainer lbContainer--inline" title="" data-xf-init="lightbox" data-lb-single-image="1" data-lb-container-zoom="1" data-lb-trigger=".js-lbImage-_xfUid-4-1619754152" data-lb-id="_xfUid-4-1619754152">
        
            <div class="lbContainer-zoomer js-lbImage-_xfUid-4-1619754152" data-src="https://i.imgur.com/dE7ixdU.png" aria-label="Zoom"></div>
        
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dE7ixdU.png" data-url="https://i.imgur.com/dE7ixdU.png" class="bbImage" data-zoom-target="1" style="">
    </div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/v9oeufm7" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/v9oeufm7</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/u0dkn2fx1bfb/29-4-pack2-21.rar.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/u0dkn2fx1bfb/29-4-pack2-21.rar.html</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/1fZ945" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/1fZ945</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/6S1TW6uV" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/6S1TW6uV</a><br>
<br>
<br>
<b><span style="color: Blue"><span style="font-size: 15px">---- Pack 28 Abril 2021 (395 MB) ----</span></span></b><br>
<br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/d8d3iq3wkhkp" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/d8d3iq3wkhkp</a><br>
<br>
<b><span style="color: Blue"><span style="font-size: 15px">---- Pack 27 Abril 2021 (445 MB) ----</span></span></b><br>
<br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/4ex7y4ny5njx" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/4ex7y4ny5njx</a><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<b><span style="font-size: 22px"><span style="color: Blue"><br>
<br>
Te gustaria recibir la prensa:<br>
<br>
-Sin Marcas<br>
-Sin Acortadores<br>
-Sin Publicidad.<br>
-Sin tiempo de espera<br>
-Ni limite de descargas<br>
-Y mucho mas<br>
<br>
Te muestro un lugar donde disfrutaras de todo esos privilegios ademas tienes una cuenta de: Netflix, Amazon Prime Video, HBO GO o Disney+ ilimitado de regalo por la compra. (elije el que te guste)<br>
<br>
Si estás interesado envíame un correo a (<a href="mailto:gptiago48gp@gmail.com">gptiago48gp@gmail.com</a>) te esperamos!<br>
<br>
</span></span></b><br>
<br>
<br>
<b><span style="color: Red"><span style="font-size: 26px">---- Prensa Nacional 29 Abril 2021 ----</span></span><br>
<span style="color: Blue"><span style="font-size: 15px">---- Click en la Imagen Para Descargar (MixLoads Sin Acortadores) ----</span></span></b><br>
<br>
<br>
1a<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<b><span style="color: red"><span style="font-size: 26px">---- Individuales ----</span></span></b><br>
<br>
<br>
<b>---- El Correo Bizkaia ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/q105kyk0" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/q105kyk0</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/jxygsl8jetn9/29-4-correo.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/jxygsl8jetn9/29-4-correo.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/lzkj8ges2w19" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/lzkj8ges2w19</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/8wq6kkrqrfbq" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/8wq6kkrqrfbq</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/oY4VlqYy" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/oY4VlqYy</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/0EJBt80V" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/0EJBt80V</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- El Mundo ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/ocsbxs0w" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/ocsbxs0w</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/uz1posr69fta/29-4-mundo.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/uz1posr69fta/29-4-mundo.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/1rcb2bxzo2zb" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/1rcb2bxzo2zb</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/xzu5iolpx5ac" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/xzu5iolpx5ac</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/Qr60" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/Qr60</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/vatv8ijO" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/vatv8ijO</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- Marca ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/ncr9e89u" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/ncr9e89u</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/mw1h81je6m9m/29-4-marca.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/mw1h81je6m9m/29-4-marca.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/glvhhtkeixdz" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/glvhhtkeixdz</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/np62tx877sy0" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/np62tx877sy0</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/Bf7wcj" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/Bf7wcj</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/v5gs4Z" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/v5gs4Z</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- El País ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/eg36x66t" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/eg36x66t</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/ckrblwb6hc16/29-4-pais.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/ckrblwb6hc16/29-4-pais.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/9zlydcvv5mel" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/9zlydcvv5mel</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/4ccvhhgyna0a" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/4ccvhhgyna0a</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/kl37i" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/kl37i</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/2J3E3npY" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/2J3E3npY</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- Expansión ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/oib2tgpn" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/oib2tgpn</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/fkp0d9elice2/29-4-expan.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/fkp0d9elice2/29-4-expan.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/13em04x4qg4x" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/13em04x4qg4x</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/8m1td0tdtxgc" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/8m1td0tdtxgc</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/Rzrpl" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/Rzrpl</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/107q5FN" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/107q5FN</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- ABC ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/n7gklwww" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/n7gklwww</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/dixh2sari562/29-4-abc.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/dixh2sari562/29-4-abc.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/2ksyup1daw6b" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/2ksyup1daw6b</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/a105ay4sijvu" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/a105ay4sijvu</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/n0Ps2" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/n0Ps2</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/sRsoR5So" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/sRsoR5So</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- AS ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/h10szizq" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/h10szizq</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/ofzm8cnxdq79/29-4-as.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/ofzm8cnxdq79/29-4-as.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/3jlged5gzhdl" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/3jlged5gzhdl</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/f503u5rnb5le" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/f503u5rnb5le</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/vxnF7" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/vxnF7</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/J7XY8I" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/J7XY8I</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- Sport ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/i88l2qzp" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/i88l2qzp</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/bab6rf55hjx2/29-4-sport.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/bab6rf55hjx2/29-4-sport.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/ebexysvxijif" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/ebexysvxijif</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/sqp8b0qx1ht0" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/sqp8b0qx1ht0</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/Yt5EG" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/Yt5EG</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/fk9Nt9z" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/fk9Nt9z</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- Mundo Deportivo ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/42paoq7h" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/42paoq7h</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/sneq95bhu1je/29-4-md.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/sneq95bhu1je/29-4-md.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/m2qmxoc6g8fp" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/m2qmxoc6g8fp</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/qyhib1pnwxds" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/qyhib1pnwxds</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/GKvB" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/GKvB</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/aWs5e" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/aWs5e</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- La Razón ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/kfnt6nfx" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/kfnt6nfx</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/wbbq8dbs1amm/29-4-razon.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/wbbq8dbs1amm/29-4-razon.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/q3c7qhh1blmi" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/q3c7qhh1blmi</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/qpdzceh8jkkl" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/qpdzceh8jkkl</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/Fqq0Z4" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/Fqq0Z4</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/lRtNtmd" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/lRtNtmd</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- La Vanguardia ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/2z0u8w9a" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/2z0u8w9a</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/dyzvzoogfdne/29-4-vgda.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/dyzvzoogfdne/29-4-vgda.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/yuxax3w6gydr" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/yuxax3w6gydr</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/wj1ofrfjzeq5" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/wj1ofrfjzeq5</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/U9Qu7xen" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/U9Qu7xen</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/AvhkXQ" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/AvhkXQ</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- La Voz de Galicia ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/ehpzcgus" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/ehpzcgus</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/wjn4qh8d9d1i/29-4-lvg.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/wjn4qh8d9d1i/29-4-lvg.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/cisww73dxsch" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/cisww73dxsch</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/hv04jp8xtrfh" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/hv04jp8xtrfh</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/3UNkiNK" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/3UNkiNK</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/UdAB83m4" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/UdAB83m4</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- El Economista ----</b><br>
<br>
<b>---- Cinco Días ----</b><br>
<br>
<b>---- El Periodico de Catalunya ----</b><br>
<br>
<b>---- Córdoba ----</b><br>
<br>
<b>---- El Periodico de Aragón ----</b><br>
<br>
<b>---- El Periodico Mediterraneo ----</b><br>
<br>
<b>---- El Periodico de Extremadura ----</b><br>
<br>
<b>---- 20 Minutos Madrid ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/1efipn2b" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/1efipn2b</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/i08otj72mntl/29-4-20mm.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/i08otj72mntl/29-4-20mm.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/udj4kfephsih" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/udj4kfephsih</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/sd1Qe8" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/sd1Qe8</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- 20 Minutos Barcelona ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/a38ocwp9" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/a38ocwp9</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/k9pbgmjrhuf6/29-4-20mb.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/k9pbgmjrhuf6/29-4-20mb.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/o55rubojobs4" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/o55rubojobs4</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/DPZ74" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/DPZ74</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- Viva Malága ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/5lnwm93d" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/5lnwm93d</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/zenwsttjtsk3/29-4-vmalaga.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/zenwsttjtsk3/29-4-vmalaga.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/jvi309plzmtz" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/jvi309plzmtz</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/N0s0Hep3" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/N0s0Hep3</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- Viva Sevilla ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/0fm8a537" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/0fm8a537</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/q5inmv91s6rl/29-4-vsevilla.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/q5inmv91s6rl/29-4-vsevilla.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/cafk4jobq7c0" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/cafk4jobq7c0</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/1EiVc5t" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/1EiVc5t</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- La Nueva España ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/kh4cy3n6" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/kh4cy3n6</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/7tu5z3aa1m45/29-4-lne.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/7tu5z3aa1m45/29-4-lne.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/dtaz4dvw3y11" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/dtaz4dvw3y11</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/eix054ds7f5o" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/eix054ds7f5o</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/D024b" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/D024b</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/bo5oymp" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/bo5oymp</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- La Gaceta de Salamanca ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/7xck04iu" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/7xck04iu</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/b2lanmmbf6qh/29-4-gaceta.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/b2lanmmbf6qh/29-4-gaceta.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/mgfnyv2eyzup" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/mgfnyv2eyzup</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/755d0s389o1i" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/755d0s389o1i</a><br>
<br>
```

SO, the question is: **HOW AM I ABLE TO RETRIEVE THE FOLLOWING LINKS FROM THIS HTML TRE**E:

```html
<b>---- La Nueva España ----</b><br>
<br>
<a href="http://uploaded.net/file/kh4cy3n6" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">http://uploaded.net/file/kh4cy3n6</a><br>
<a href="https://katfile.com/7tu5z3aa1m45/29-4-lne.pdf.html" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://katfile.com/7tu5z3aa1m45/29-4-lne.pdf.html</a><br>
<a href="https://up-load.io/dtaz4dvw3y11" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://up-load.io/dtaz4dvw3y11</a><br>
<a href="https://mixloads.com/eix054ds7f5o" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://mixloads.com/eix054ds7f5o</a><br>
<a href="https://tny.so/D024b" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://tny.so/D024b</a><br>
<a href="https://bitfly.io/bo5oymp" target="_blank" class="link link--external" rel="noopener">https://bitfly.io/bo5oymp</a><br>
<br>
<b>---- La Gaceta de Salamanca ----</b><br>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML of the page in your answer as text, properly formatted. A link is helpful but the HTML could change tomorrow and that would make this question obsolete. Also, you need a login to access the page you are referring to and the site is not in English.

Comment: And please don't use the phrase "XXX is not working". Tell us how it failed: what results were you expecting and what result did you get? Diagnosis of any problem starts by looking at the symptoms.

Comment: Just those 6 links?

Answer (score 1):

A basic way would be

```
//a[preceding-sibling::b[.='---- La Nueva España ----'] and following-sibling::b[.='---- La Gaceta de Salamanca ----']]
```

To more generally iterate over elements grouped by common dividers, you may find this answer useful:

[Scrapy xpath with following sibling between two h2 tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978425/scrapy-xpath-with-following-sibling-between-two-h2-tags/66978756#66978756)