# Xpath how to get all following-sibling until next specific tag comes

Tags: html, xpath

I have a question of xpath which I need to collect.

I want to collect all following-siblings until next strong tag.

To collect this data, assuming two variables like below.

- Strong : "Key" parameter
- Between Strong tag : "Value" parameter

```html
<strong>A</strong>
<p>a</p>
<strong>B</strong>
<p>b</p>
<strong>C</strong>
<p>c</p>
<strong>D</strong>
<ul>
  <li>
    · d1
    <em>d2</em>
  </li>
</ul>
<strong>E</strong>
<p>e</p>
```

The result I want is

- key: A , value: a
- key: B , value: b
- key: C , value: c
- key: D , value: d1 d2
- key: E , value: e

In code, there is no strong after **E**.

Plz help me to find out the solution. :(

Comment: This technique may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978425/scrapy-xpath-with-following-sibling-between-two-h2-tags/66978756#66978756

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem is quite tricky if you're using XPath 1.0 (in fact, it's not trivial with later versions either). In many cases the most practical solution is to let your XPath over-retrieve and then filter the results in the receiving application.

In your particular example, asking for "all the following sibling elements up to the next `strong`" is the same as asking for "the immediately following sibling element", which can be obtained as `following-sibling::*[1]`.

But in the more general case, you need something like

```
following-sibling::* except following-sibling::strong/(. | following-sibling::*)
```

which would be valid in XPath 2.0, but there is no `except` operator in XPath 1.0 (also, you can't use parens like this in 1.0)

You can craft an except operator in 1.0 using the rewrite

```
A except B ==> A[count(.|B)=0]
```

but it gets fairly horrendous.

Move to XPath 3.1 if you can!